# query for delete all data in table that priviusely entered and insert new data

Tags: mysql

Here (Delete * avg_month_val1) part not work well but rest of code ok

Delete * avg_month_val1 and
INSERT  INTO `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1`  ( `year` , `month` ,  `evep` , `sunshine_hrs` , 
`rainfall` , `max_temp` , `min_temp` ) 
SELECT

```
 year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year,
 month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as month,
```

round(avg(evep),2) ,
    round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2),
  round(sum(rainfall),2),
    round(AVG(max_temp),2) ,

```
round(avg(min_temp),2)
```

from   reg_data3
GROUP BY

```
 year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) ORDER BY 1 Desc  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
mysql_query(UPDATE `clima_data` SET `key` = '$value', `key2` = '$value2' WHERE `year` = '$year'")
```

You dont need the where, but maybe you want it. Im not sure this is what you want, its not very clear to me from the question

Comment: no is not, i want to delete priviousely entered data in avg_month_val1 and select another table (reg_data3) values and that values pass in to avg_month_val1 here clima_data is database it is not table